# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am getting following error

> Unable to get property 'showMsg' of undefined or null reference

on the last line of below code:

```
    Function.prototype.showMsg = function () {
        alert("This is a sample message.");
    };

    function Person() {
        this.name = "Mahesh";
    };

    var personObj = new Person();
    personObj.prototype.showMsg();
```

Actually I should be able to access `showMsg()` from `Person` instance since I have added it to the `Function.prototype`. Then why I am getting this error?

Comment: `prototype` is for constructors, not the constructed objects

Comment: oooh thats interesting, so how can I achieve similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You Understand it all Wrong

```
Function.prototype.showMsg = function () {
    alert("This is a sample message.");
};

function Person() {
    this.name = "Mahesh";
};

var personObj = new Person();
personObj.prototype.showMsg();
```

First you prototyped the function class, then create a custom class called Person, then you create an instance of Person. And then you are calling the very blue print which is showMsg which is 2 Mistakes 1 showMsg is not Bounded into the Person and then to call it if its bounded you call it directly like this

```
personObj.showMsg()
```

Will To Make This Script Work from my point of View if i got you write 
write it like this ->

```
function Person() {
 this.name = "Mahesh";
};

Person.prototype.showMsg = function () {
  alert("This is a sample message.");
};

var personObj = new Person();
personObj.showMsg();
```

my script bound the showMsg Directly to the Person Class if you need it through the Person Object and Through The Function Class To Then you have to inherit from Function Class Like This

```
Function.prototype.showMsg=function () {
   alert("This is a sample message.");
    };

function Person() {
   this.name = "Mahesh";
    };


Person.prototype = Function;
Person.prototype.constructor = Person;

var personObj = new Person();
personObj.showMsg();
```

Regards

Comment: **But then how can I make a property or method to appear as a part of all functions and their instances???** I thought I have read that `Function` is kinda base type in JavaScript and hence adding any property to its `prototype` will cause that property to appear below all functions and their instances.

Comment: Can't becuase any function in the world have a return type and even if you didnt define the return type in JavaScript its by default is Undefined